# Force deactivate pixel rows on top of the screen

Tags: screen, display-resolution

A laptop that recently came into my possession has part of the screen at the top damaged. It's current resolution is 1280 x 600, at the ratio of 16:10.

Is there anything I can do forcibly change the resolution and set it so that the few damaged top rows remain unused?

If there's any issue of incompatibility across Ubuntu, I'd  like to ask for the soon-to-be-released Xenial compatible solutuon.